# Is Date.parse and Math.abs are equal

Tags: javascript

In one of my method, i used to check the values from the dataSource with tolerance value as below

```
var xTolerance=3.14

    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(Math.abs(x[i])>xTolerance){
    //code
    }
    }
```

where x contains the values from datasource. Sometime i am getting date(Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930) from the datasource , so before checking the value with tolerance, i have converted that date to milliseconds using **Date.parse**. The datasource contain 1000 points, so the excution time get increase because of using the Date.parse method, so i have checked the value(Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930) with tolernace without converting into milliseconds. it works fine, my question is whether the below codes are same

```
x[i]=Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930           x[i]=Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930
                                    <=>      x[i]=Date.parse(x[i]);
if(Math.abs(x[i])>xTolerance){               if(Math.abs(x[i])>xTolerance){
}                                            }
```

In simple

x[i]=Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930... i am just asking whether

```
Math.abs(x[i])== Math.abs(Date.parse(x[i]))
```

is true ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean for April 1 to have an absolute value greater than 3.14?

Comment: x[i]=Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930...  i am just asking whether Math.abs(x[i])== Math.abs(Date.parse(x[i])) is true ???

Comment: I'm saying that the question is not meaningful. What is your actual problem? You are checking whether a time is within 3.14 milliseconds of January 1, 1970, which is a strange thing to be testing for since it works only for that date and nothing else.

Comment: What is `x[i]` really? A `Date` object or a string? If it is a `Date` object already, why would you parse it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will compare `Math.abs(x)` and `Math.abs(Date.parse(x))`, assuming `x` is a `Date` object:

## Math.abs(x)

According to http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.8.2,

> 15.8.2   Function Properties of the Math Object
>
> Each of the following Math object functions applies the **ToNumber** abstract operator to each
>   of its arguments (in left-to-right order if there is more than one)
>   and then performs a computation on the resulting Number value(s).

According to http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_9.htm#Section_9.3, if the argument is an object, `ToNumber` applies the following steps:

> 1. Let primValue be **ToPrimitive**(input argument, hint Number).
> 2. Return ToNumber(primValue).

According to http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.9.6,

(read http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_9.htm#Section_9.1 and http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_8.htm#Section_8.12.8 if you want full algorithm)

> Date instances inherit properties from the Date prototype object and
>   their [[Class]] internal property value is "Date". Date instances also
>   have a [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property.
>
> The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property is **time value represented by
>   this Date object**.

Then, `Math.abs(x)`, where `x` is a `Date` object, is the same as `Math.abs(y)`, where `y`y is a number containing the time value represented by `x`.

## Math.abs(Date.parse(x))

According to http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.9.4.2,

> 15.9.4.2   Date.parse (string)
>
> The parse function applies the **ToString** operator to its argument and interprets the resulting String as a date
>   and time; it returns a Number, the UTC time value corresponding to the
>   date and time. The String may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC
>   time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of
>   the String.

According to http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#ELS5_Section_15.9.5.2

> 15.9.5.2   Date.prototype.toString ( )
>
> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but
>   are intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a
>   convenient, human-readable form.
>
> NOTE
>
> For any Date value d **whose
>   milliseconds amount is zero**, the result of **Date.parse(d.toString()) is
>   equal to d.valueOf()**. See 15.9.4.2.

According to http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.9.5.8,

> 15.9.5.8   Date.prototype.valueOf ( )
>
> The valueOf function returns a Number, which is **this time value**.

Then, `Math.abs(Date.parse(x))`, where `x` is a `Date` object, is the same as `Math.abs(y)`, where `y`y is a number containing the time value of `x`.

## Conclusion

You can be sure they are equal if the milliseconds amount is zero.

If not, the results can be implementation-dependent, but I guess that in most implementations the result is the same.

## Additional notes

Note that `Date.parse` expects a string, so you don't need to use `Date.parse(x)` if `x` is already a `Date` object.

When you have doubts about the specification, you can go to

- Unofficial HTML version of the spec: http://ecma262-5.com/
- Table of contents: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Sections_TOC.htm#a-toc

Comment: If you assume that `x` is a `Date` object, then the comparison is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

The value of `Math.abs('Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930')` is `NaN`. Comparing that to any number using any operator gives `false`, except the operators `!=` and `!==` which gives `true`.

Comment: Asker says *it works fine*, so I guess he uses `Date` objects instead of strings.

Comment: @Oriol: In that case the `parseDate` call would be superflous, and the entire question moot.

Comment: Yes. My guess is that asker misinterpreted `Date.parse`

Comment: @Oriol: You are missing the point. If the value would already be a `Date` object, then parsing it is completely superflous, and comparing no-operation with a superflous operation is pointless.